# Disallow identity search Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

We have an Azure DevOps environment(online dev.azure.com/aaaa). Here we have multiple projects. Each project has multiple users.

I would like to avoid users from project A being able to mention users from project B due to privacy.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [concept of "project scoped users"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/manage-organization-collection?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops#project-scoped-user-group).

> To limit the identity selection to just those users and groups added to a project, perform the following procedure for your organization and projects.
>
> - Enable the Limit user visibility and collaboration to specific projects preview feature for the organization.
> - Add the users to your project(s) as described in Add users to a project or team. Users added to a team are automatically added to the project and team group.
> - Open Organizations Settings>Security>Permissions and choose Project-Scoped Users. Choose the Members tab. Add all users and groups that you want to scope to the project(s) you've added them to.

Comment: Thanks jessehouwing, this is exactly what I was looking for :)